# How do i get my java program to import the javacv libraries properly in linux (EDIT - now getting unsatisfiedLinkError)

Tags: java, linux, opencv, raspberry-pi

I am currently trying to get opencv and javacv to work on my raspberry pi.

I have followed [this tutorial](http://salaboy.com/2013/06/14/using-javacv-in-the-raspberry-pi-linux-arm/)

I believe i have everything set up properly.

The current folder paths look like this.

```
/home/pi/build - The three javacv libs (javacpp.jar, javacv.jar and javacv-linux-arm.jar)


the opencv jar is located at
/home/pi/build/opencv/opencv-2.4.11/release/bin - opencv-2411.jar
```

OpenCv comes with some java examples the one i am looking at is located at

```
home/pi/build/opencv/opencv-2.4.11/samples/java/eclipse/Hellocv/src/Main.java
```

Here is the code itself.

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to OpenCV " + Core.VERSION);
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        Mat m  = Mat.eye(3, 3, CvType.CV_8UC1);
        System.out.println("m = " + m.dump());
    }

}
```

When i compile it however (with or without the classpath included), i get the error

```
package.org.opencv.core does not exist.
```

EDIT - if it is relevant i am also using the new Raspberry Pi 2 B+

EDIT 2 /3 (improved detail

It compiles with hits

```
javac -cp .:/home/pi/build/opencv/opencv-2.4.11/release/bin/opencv-2411.jar:/home/pi/build/opencv/opencv-2.4.11/release/lib Main.java
```

But then fails here when i run it, at the line "system.loadlibrary"

```
java -cp .:/home/pi/build/opencv/opencv-2.4.11/release/bin/opencv-2411.jar:/home/pi/build/opencv/opencv-2.4.11/release/lib Main
```

The error is

```
unsatisfiedlinkerror: no opencv_java2411 in java.library.path
```

I have tried looking this up, but most of the solutions are for windows. I am providing a direct link to the opencv_java2411.jar file in my classpath so i am unsure as to why it won't run.

Comment: Can you post the commands you're using to compile?

Comment: inside of the location of the "Main.java" file

I have tried:
    javac Main.java
    javac -cp <theclasspath> Main.java

I also just tried your suggestion of 
    javac -Djava.library.path=/home/pi/build/javacv.jar Main.java

But i do not think that the syntax was correct.

Comment: The -Djava.library.path suggestion is for executing the compiled jar, before I noticed it's the compilation that's causing issues. What worked for me before was installing OpenCV jars into my maven repo and using them as a dependency in a maven project which required OpenCV.

Comment: I get the feeling that with my issue it is just that it cannot find the libraries themselves, should all of the jars be inside the opencv release bin folder?

Comment: Hey @nomis there has been an edit added with some progress, if you could take a look i'd appreciate that a lot.

Comment: just saying - javacv != opencv's java wrappers. (javacv and javacpp are 3rd party wrappers with significantly differing api / framework)

Comment: Yeah i realise that, for this simple program they won't be needed. 

I had them there are before i was confused as to whether they were needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On reflection i think a large part of why this was not compiling was due to it being one of the 'eclipse' examples and i was not trying to compile this in eclipse.

The solution i came to in the end was to use Ant to build and compile the java code.

My main source figuring out how to do this was [this opencv page](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html)

I should note that the example they show on that page is available in the samples sub-folder so you can save yourself some time by using what is already provided.

Thanks as well to @nomis

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue, I fixed it just by doing it:
Copy opencv-2411.jar file to the location where the program is (Main.java)
and extract opencv-2411.jar file

```
jar xf opencv-2411.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the java.library.path property pointing at the location of the java OpenCV libs when you're running the jar (from command line or in Eclipse or whatever IDE you're using). For example if you have a runnable jar try

```
java -jar -Djava.library.path=/home/pi/build/lib app.jar
```

This also assumes that you've built OpenCV and java was one of the modules built. A good tutorial to follow is at http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html

Comment: I checked the site and when i follow the Ant example everything works fine.

It seems that when i want to just compile a simple Main.java is when it has issues.

on the code sample above it fails when it gets to "system.loadlibrary"


This is with me currently doing this:


    javac -cp .:/home/pi/build/opencv/opencv-2.4.11/release/bin/opencv-2411.jar:/home/pi/build/opencv/opencv-2.4.11/release/lib Main.java

This compiles

    java -cp .:/home/pi/build/opencv/opencv-2.4.11/release/bin/opencv-2411.jar:/home/pi/build/opencv/opencv-2.4.11/release/lib Main

Is when it fails.